# CSS | Стили, полоса

Tags: css

Не знаю как называется.
Нашел одну, но потерялся в стилях, т.к. начинаю разбираться в этой области.

Как сделать такую же полосу:

[image]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Это называется прогресс бар.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.main{
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.main::after{
    content: '';
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: grey;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: не так - там box-shadow inset ...